# Laravel 5 - updating hasMany / belongsTo related record

Tags: php, laravel-5, has-many, belongs-to

Laravel (5) newbie question. Building Projects / Tasks project.

Routes:

```
Route::resource('project', 'ProjectsController');
Route::resource('project.task', 'TasksController');
```

Projects model:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tasks');
}
```

Tasks model:

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Projects');
}
```

Now trying to edit/update specific task. 
Route to task is project/{project}/task/{task}/edit

** Question - Are my Edit and Update functions in TasksController correct? It works, but not really sure if all should be done that way... **

```
public function edit($project_id, $task_id)
{
    $Task = Tasks::find($task_id);
    return view('task_edit', compact('Task'));
}

public function update($project_id, $task_id)
{
    $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');
    $Task = Tasks::find($task_id);
    $Task->update($input);

    return Redirect::route('project.show', array($Task->project->id));
}
```

Comment: If you've assigned a $fillable array on your Task model then you don't need to remove _method from $input, you can send Input::all () and only the fillable columns will be updated. You should probably  implement some validation, too.

Comment: Thanks. Will try with Input::all() only. And yes, need to implement validation. What about $project_id parameter. I'm confused whether $project_id parameter which is passed to both edit / update (also create and store) functions should be somehow used or not?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have any validation. Not sure if intended or not. You can use `Request::except('field');` to get all values except unwanted one. other than that Things look good. Is there anything you are concerned about?

Comment: Thanks Pawel. I'm confused whether $project_id parameter which is passed to both edit / update (also create and store) functions should be somehow used or not

Comment: Since you have a one to many relation you could even skip the project/id from route. Each task has unique id which is used to retrieve the record and update it. If you had a many to many relation you would need both to find and update the record and any extra parameters would be on a pivot table.